# Hibernate multiple fetch with abstract class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

Hello I have following classes:

```
public class OrderTemplate {

    <other fields>

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orderTemplate", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Column(name="order_template_input")
    private Set<OrderTemplateInput> orderTemplateInputs;

}
```

Now i have Abstract Class orderTemplateInput like this:

```
public abstract class OrderTemplateInput {

    <other fields>
    @Column(name="text", nullable = false)
    protected String text;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_template_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    protected OrderTemplate orderTemplate;

}
```

And two classes extends this one:

```
public class OrderTemplateTextInput extends OrderTemplateInput {

    @JsonProperty(value="type")
    public OrderTemplateInputType getType() {
        return OrderTemplateInputType.TEXT;
    }
}
```

And this one:

```
public class OrderTemplateSelectInput extends OrderTemplateInput {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orderTemplateSelectInput", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<InputValue> inputValues;

    @JsonProperty(value="type")
    public OrderTemplateInputType getType() {
        return OrderTemplateInputType.SELECT;
    }
}
```

First of all i want to avoid fetchType.Eager. So i want to get all orderTemplate with associations collections. I have following hql query:

```
@Query("SELECT distinct o FROM OrderTemplate o JOIN FETCH o.orderTemplateInputs JOIN FETCH o.orderTemplateInputs oIn JOIN FETCH oIn.inputValues")
```

It's not working only in one case when the OrderTemplate has only collection of OrderTemplateTextInput. In the list of OrderTemplate there is only OrderTemplate with OrderTemplateSelectInput and with both select and text. How should look like the query to get all associations collections?